# How to pass an Arraylist from Activity to Widget

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to pass an arraylist from activity to widget but my app crushes at the my widget provider.

I gave details below.

Here is part of code from my first activity:

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                AppProviderWidget.class);
        intent1.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
        // Use an array and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS instead of
        // AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        // since it seems the onUpdate() is only fired on that:
        int[] ids = widgetIDs;
        intent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        intent1.putExtra("widgetlist", result);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);
```

**I sent data is here :**

```
    intent1.putExtra("widgetlist", result);
```

**And code from the AppProviderWidget onReceive method**

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    ArrayList<DuyuruHaber> arl = new ArrayList<DuyuruHaber>();
    arl = (ArrayList<DuyuruHaber>) intent
            .getSerializableExtra("widgetlist");

    try {

            liste = arl;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Log",e.toString());
    }}
```

**AppProviderWidget.onReceive(AppProviderWidget.java:170)**

```
arl = (ArrayList<DuyuruHaber>) intent
            .getSerializableExtra("widgetlist");
```

**my log cat**

```
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver widget.AppProviderWidget: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at widget.AppProviderWidget.onReceive(AppProviderWidget.java:170)
08-23 16:28:01.684: E/AndroidRuntime(10067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
```

*Thanks for the help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your code you are trying to pass ArrayList of DuyuruHaber objects. To pass list of your custom object , your custom object (DuyuruHaber) must implements "Serializable" iterface.

You can user another Easy way to pass ArrayList of DuyuruHaber objects using static method.

**In your AppProviderWidget class create method**

```
private static ArrayList<DuyuruHaber> widgetList;

public static void setDuyuruHaberList(ArrayList<DuyuruHaber> data){
 AppProviderWidget.widgetList = data;
}
```

**From your Activity**

Before calling intent

```
AppProviderWidget.setDuyuruHaberList(result);
```

Comment: Thank you I didnt want to use static way but I think need to use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myKey", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

to retrieve it you need to use getIntent() method

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("myKey");
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer. But not working. I get same error.